# Tagbar with asciidoc doesn't work

Tags: plugin

I have problem with configuration the tagbar plugin in nvim for asciidoc. I don't see headers in tagbar's sidebar. I have universal ctags installed, when I run:

```bash
ctags -R --languages=asciidoc --kinds-asciidoc=sSTtuac .
```

It generates entries in the `tags` file, but with the command

```
ctags --list-languages |grep -i asciidoc
```

I get `"Asciidoc [disabled]"`. TagbarDebug doesn't have any errors.
Currently I have recent nvim and manjaro.
I know that universal ctags supports asciidoc format.
Should I add something into nvim file configuration?

Comment: You wrote *I know that universal ctags supports asciidoc format* but your command-line says it's disabled… (and when I run the same command, I get `Asciidoc` as output). So I suspect you don't have the right entries? (Unless adding `--languages=asciidoc` changes the second command)

Comment: Even with ctags correctly enabled and generating tags, tagbar won't show them.